# Send Data from Fragment to Main Activity through NavGraph

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-activity, android-navigation, android-deep-link

In my app, I'm using a Single Activity with multiple Fragments Architecture and I navigate between them using the Navigation Library. Within one of the fragments, I have multiple categories, each associated with an ID. When a category is clicked, I take the user to that respective category explainer screen with the code below.

```
    val directions = MainNavGraphDirections.launchFragmentWithThisCategoryId(categoryId!!)
            onRoute(AppRoute.Directions(directions))
```

The above code sends them to the explainer screen associated with the associated `categoryId`. All is well until this point, the right explainer screen gets launched based on the `categoryId`. Within this explainer screen, I have a deep-link with a tag `chatbot://fragment/wizardintro` that is supposed to let the main activity know the specific follow-up fragment to send the user to. I denote all the fragments that can receive this deep-link with the code below.

```
companion object{
        const val DEEP_LINK = "chatbot://fragment/wizardintro"
    }
```

In the MainActivity, I have a method that receives all the different deep linking intents and matches them to the tags that will launch the respective category fragment with the code below.

```
 override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent)
        intent?.data?.toString().also { deepLink ->
            when (deepLink) {
               IntroductionFragment.DEEP_LINK ->{
                        val categoryId = intent?.getLongExtra("categoryId", 0L)
                        val directions = MainNavGraphDirections.actionGlobalGoalWizard(categoryId)
                        navController.popBackStack()
                        navController.navigate(directions)
                }    
    }
```

Now my problem arises when I try to retrieve this `categoryId` in the Main Activity and pass it to the next fragment. I don't get anything and only the default Long gets passed along. I think the function override fun onNewIntent(intent: Intent?) { } in the MainActivity recieve any intent. To be clear, these intents are sent from the explainer fragment which is technically a fragment that loads a json. Within the json there is a "route": {"type": "route", "url": "chatbot:///fragment/wizardintro"

In the MainActivity, the onNewIntent functions receive these intents unpacks them with this line `intent?.data?.toString().also ...`then in the when statement picks a fragment that has a matching `chatbot:///fragment/wizardintro`

I said all this to say that the main activity doesn't actually gets the categoryId, it simply picks launching the neccessary fragment without actually having anything associated with the `categoryId`

This makes me think that the first clicked categoryId doesn't actually get passed to the MainActivity. Although, to me, this seems like it shouldn't be this hard to pass objects/data from a fragment to an activity. What am I missing? What can I read to educate myself more on this?
Thanks for your time and responses!

Comment: Hey, why do you want the `MainActivity` to send you to that fragment, when the fragment can actually send you to that fragment? is there a certain reason? If not, I have the solution for you

Comment: @Nizar It's cause I have multiple deep-linking intents and I use the MainActivity to determine which fragment to launch based on the tag the deep link comes in with

Comment: You are aware that in `navgraph` you can actually deeplink straight to the fragment, right?

Comment: Yeah, but the pattern that has been established with this project requires me to link it back to the MainActivity. For other instances, I did just deep link directly to the fragment I needed to pop-up

Comment: So, I guess Fragment-To-Fragment navigation won't be a solution, right ? You kind of want to pass it through the MainActivity so that you can make use of those DeepLinks you have established, right?

Comment: @Nizar  Yes, essentially, I need to get the `categoryId` from the first click and cascade it down to the last fragment in the chain.

Comment: By any chance can you share the `MainNavGraphDirections.launchFragmentWithThisCategoryId` code? After all, it seems like the `intent?.data` does not contain the `categoryId`...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206302/discussion-between-princeps-polycap-and-nizar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since we already got to the conclusion that `MainActivity` is not getting `categoryId`, you just need to pass that `categoryId` with the `deep-link`.

However, there is no need for any communication from `Fragment` to `Activity`.
You could achieve the same result through communication only between `Fragment` to `Fragment`, and `Activity` to `Fragment`.

---

What you want to do is to look more closely on `deep-links` and `android navigation` in the AndroidDocs, [click here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/).

As you can tell, there are different ways to go around this, starting with `arguments` for each fragment. Assigning `categoryId` as an `argument` to the Fragment would help you use the `navigationController` and `navigate` to the new `Fragment`, while passing the `categoryId` to it.

Now, I am aware that you also wish to launch it with a `deep-link`; there's also a good explanation on [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link). According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-deep-link), you can place `arguments` in `deep-links` in the following manner...

> Placeholders in the form of `{placeholder_name}` match one or more characters. For example, `http://www.example.com/users/{id}` matches `http://www.example.com/users/4`. The Navigation component attempts to parse the placeholder values into appropriate types by **matching placeholder names to the defined arguments** that are defined for the deep link destination. **If no argument with the same name is defined, a default String type is used for the argument value.**

---

The `navigation` is something amazing and capable, you just need to be aware of everything it can actually do. You can even bind it to a `BottomNavBar`, with extremely minimal amount of code.

Try going over the [AndroidDocs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/) about it, and it'll grow on you for sure.

Comment: Thanks @Nizar for sharing this. After reading the linked docs, I realized that channeling all the intents to the `onNewIntent` function in the MainActivity seems like an anti-pattern. Thus, I opted to remove that function and change the JSON so that it passes the ID in the deepLink like this `<deepLink app:uri="chatbot://fragment/wizardintro/{categoryId}"/>`. I also removed `android:launchMode="singleTask"` from the manifest which allowed me to launch the needed fragment with the right `categoryId`

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question ;D well done!